# Is "it" the proper pronoun in the following sentence?

Tags: pronouns

Is "it" the correct pronoun in the following?

> A dog chased a cat. It barked very loudly.

I am trying to create an example for pronoun ambiguity.

Comment: If you’re looking for another example: ‘He tied his shoes.’ might do nicely. The ‘his’ could refer to either the subject, or to some other individual. The first case could be expressed unambiguously by making the possessive form reflexive (‘his own shoes’ in this case), but the second case cannot be stated unambiguously in English using pronouns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes "it" can be correctly used in the sentence:

> A dog chased a cat. It barked very loudly.

However, if the sex of the dog is known, "he" or "she'" could also be used.

Note that context makes the pronoun not ambiguous for anyone who knows that dogs bark and cats do not.

Comment: Thanks! The example should be my starting point to show that syntax and semantics are not enough to resolve references and that `world knowledge` is a crucial indicator.

Comment: "Note that context makes the pronoun not ambiguous for anyone who knows that dogs bark and cats do not" - [Cats _can_ bark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hUPWYUWnvA).  Just being pedantic.  :-P

Comment: @Vikki: What about the [original video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAox2OrJ_3I) mentioned in the top right corner?